# How to log out of Facebook when using a custom login button, on iOS using FBSDKLoginKit?

Tags: ios, facebook, fbsdkloginkit

I am implementing a custom login button in my iOS app, using the `FBSDKLoginKit` CocoaPod, version 4.8.0. I already have log in working, but I can't figure out how to log out of Facebook. I am already calling `logOut` on an instance of `FBSDKLoginManager`, but that only seems to clear the `currentAccessToken` value. When I tap my login button again, I see a screen that looks like this:

[image: Already authorized screen]

I want to be able to log in as a different Facebook user. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the new version of the Facebook iOS SDK (4.6 and above, I think) the default behaviour of login uses Safari View Controller. So if you are logged into Safari and have already logged into your app using Facebook, it will not ask for your credentials again and show you that screen. If you want to log in as a different user, then you will need to log out of Facebook in Safari in which case the login dialog should ask for your credentials. Also, you can remove the app from your [app settings](https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications) and try to login in which case it will show you the permissions screen. This behaviour of the login dialog probably follows from [the best practices](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/reference/current/FB.Logout#besties) where a logout from an app should not cause logout from Facebook itself.